# angular page contains no scroll even the components already elapsed

Tags: html, angular, scroll, angular-material

I create a component with the HTML , everything is working fine and I have a lot of input fields and content but I notice that some div content and input field are already below and no longer visible on screen but the page did not show any scroll so I can scroll. What is the problem with this and how to solve this on ?

on the first pic below you can see that text is cut because there is no scroll and scroll does not continue to the bottom , any ideas?

[image]

[image: as you can see there is no scroll bar at the corner] , I cant see the other text fields below. Any idea guys would be much appreciated. Thanks.

#html code

```
<div>
        <div fxLayout="row">
            <span id="text" style="padding-top: 50px;">Enter user's email (*)</span>
        </div>
        <mat-card class="custom" style="width: 684px;">
            <mat-divider class="custom"></mat-divider>
            <mat-card-content>
                <div>
                    <div fxLayout="column">
                        <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <mat-label>Username or Email</mat-label>
                            <input matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: right;">
                        <button (click)="getStarted('brian.christ@bermwood.com')" mat-flat-button color="primary"
                            class="v-btn-sml" id="get-started-button">
                            Get Started
                        </button>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
        <mat-divider class="custom"></mat-divider>
        <div fxLayout="row">
            <span id="text" style="padding-top: 20px;">Enter user's information (*)</span>
        </div>
        <mat-card class="custom" style="width: 684px;">
            <mat-card-content>
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
                    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                        <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <mat-label>Firstname</mat-label>
                            <input matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                        <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <mat-label>Lastname</mat-label>
                            <input matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start">
                    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                        <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
                            <input matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
                    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                        <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <mat-label>Company Name</mat-label>
                            <input matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                        <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
                            <input matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
        <mat-divider class="custom"></mat-divider>
        <div fxLayout="row">
            <span id="text" style="padding-top: 20px;">Assign a security role (*)</span>
        </div>
        <mat-card class="custom" style="width: 684px;">
            <mat-divider class="custom"></mat-divider>
            <mat-card-content>
                <div>
                    <div fxLayout="column">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <mat-label>Security Role</mat-label>
                            <select matNativeControl id="mySelectId">
                                <option value="" disabled selected></option>
                                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                            </select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
```

#my css

```
#createuser-details-container {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#create-details-header {
  background-color: #012b56;
}

#create-details-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#create-details-header-content {
  padding: 16px 20px 0px 20px;
  z-index: 20;
}

.container-header-padding {
  padding: 24px 124px 36px 124px;
}

.selected-card {
  background-color: #007dff;
}

.selected-radio {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.option-header {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}

.section-title {
  padding-top: 48px;
}

.section-title-child {
  padding-top: 36px;
}

.summary-title {
  padding-top: 16px;
}

.team-member-title {
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.cancel-button {
  color: rgba(0, 125, 255, 1);
  padding-left: 8.5vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pre-find-label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  padding-right: 36px;
}

.save-button {
  padding-right: 9.8vw;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.mat-checkbox-checked-indeterminate.mat-primary .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #007dff !important;
}

.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-primary .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #007dff !important;
}

.mat-radio-button.mat-primary .mat-radio-inner-circle {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /*inner circle color change*/
}

.mat-radio-button.mat-primary.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle {
  border-color: #ffffff;
  /*outer ring color change*/
}

.summary-label-empty {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}

#footer-createuser {
  padding: 16px 0px 16px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  z-index: 8;
}

.sticky-user {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 32px;
}

#text {
  width: 710px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.custom.mat-card {
  width: 684px;
  height: 194px;
  padding: 32px, 24px, 32px, 24px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: static;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
}

.custom.mat-divider {
  width: 720px;
  height: 194px;
  padding: 32px, 24px, 32px, 24px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: static;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
}

.get-started-button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 32px 0px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 120px;
  height: 42px;
  width: 181px;
}
```

#mytscode

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TransactionsDto } from 'src/app/core/models/transactions/transactions-dto';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-user-dialog',
  templateUrl: './create-user-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-user-dialog.component.css'],
})
export class CreateUserDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  model = new TransactionsDto();
  isInProgress: boolean;

  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {});
  }

  getStarted(name: string) {}

  close() {
    this._router.navigate(['transactions']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking some information like the browser you are using, your parent container stylings, or your custom CSS stylings (if any) that are affecting this setup.

To answer your question -

1. Scrollbar gets added automatically unless we deliberately force it to not appear.
2. Make sure that you are running this code on a modern browser, zoomed to 100%.
3. Your parent container stylings may be affecting the view. Make sure to check them.

Here's a StackBlitz that I created from the same html code and it is working perfectly fine.
https://angular-9-material-starter.stackblitz.io/

Comment: I will add my css Sir , a sec.

Comment: I have added my css to the questions

Comment: added including the ts file